# select only text input names from POST

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove submit button value from $_POST form data PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784460/remove-submit-button-value-from-post-form-data-php)

I want to echo the names of the text inputs, but this also echos the submit input name, how can I change it so that it ony selects inputs with type="text" in them?

```
<?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

       foreach( $_POST as $value){
       echo $value;
    } 
  }
?>
 <form action="ajax.html" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="a">
    <input type="text" name="b">
    <input type="text" name="c">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: You can't differentiate the type of the input when you submit your form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POST doesn't know how the data was gathered. The only way you could do this is like so:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($key != 'submit')
        {
            echo $value;
        }
    }
}
?>
<form action="ajax.html" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="a">
    <input type="text" name="b">
    <input type="text" name="c">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

just omit the name attribute on the submit button.

Comment: What about other stuff like `select` or `checkbox`, if any.

Answer (score 2):

You can include an if statement in your foreach loop:

```
foreach($_POST as $value) {
    if ($value == "submit") {
        continue;
    }
    echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($_POST as $name => $value)
{
    if ($name != "submit")
        echo $value."<br/>";
}
```